# How to deal with elements that only contain absolutely positioned children?

Tags: html, css

I have a box that contains 2 absolutely positioned header and paragraph elements, I am experimenting on ways on how to center text and I tried tinkering using the method from this [site](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/simplest-way-horizontally-and).

Now the issue here isn't about ways on how to position text, because that's not my problem so you should not address that.

My problem is this.

How to make the parent element contain it's children?

Since the parent element contains elements that are absolutely positioned, that means the children are not in the flow and in turn the parent collapses.

Now this is a shocker, because I discovered that the containing/wrapping methods used in the same way for floats DO NOT WORK AT ALL.

1. Clearfix method.
2. Clearing div method
3. Overflow method.

They do not work at all!

The only method that decently works is the "Explicit Height" method which is very inefficient, unpredictable (might break on smaller windows) and not fluid.

Here is a simple, fixed-width rounded corner box who's "h1" and "p" elements I'd like to center using the above referred method.

Sample CSS,

```
body {
    margin: 8px;
    padding: 0;}

.box {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 335px; 
    position: relative;
    background: #40331A url(bottom.gif) no-repeat left bottom;}

.inner {
    background: url(top.gif) no-repeat left top;}

.box h2 {
    width: 180px;
    height: 27px;
    top: 50%;}

.box p {
    width: 120px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 50%;}

.box h2, .box p {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;}
```

Sample markup,

```
<div class="box">
 <div class="inner">
  <h2>This is a heading.</h2>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

So my question.

Is there any simple way to make a parent element contain its absolutely positioned children?

Comment: I was experimenting and I just found it out and there were no results on google too.

Answer (score 2):

The entire point of absolutely-positioned elements is that the parent of those elements should be laid out as if those elements were never there. If you want the layout of your parent element to take into account its children, don't position them absolutely.

Since you're not including any relevant properties other than `position: absolute`, it seems completely superfluous, given that absolutely-positioned elements default to their static positions anyway. Just remove that declaration. It doesn't get any simpler than that.

The reason none of those methods work is because they are designed for floats, and absolutely-positioned elements are not floats:

1. You can't really "clear" anything that isn't a float.
2. Ditto.
3. The reason setting `overflow` works for floats is due to a consequence of the way floats participate in block layout, which does not apply to absolutely-positioned elements. What exactly this entails falls outside the scope of this question, but read up on block formatting contexts.

Comment: I just need a way for the parent to contain its children because I feel it might be useful in the future, that's all.

Comment: How can you expect a box to contain something you just took out of the box? That's why I'm telling you to just leave it in the box.

Comment: But if I don't use position:absolute then I can't center the elements.